# How to prevent cmd prompt popup while executing system() through c/c++ exe

Tags: windows, cmd

I am executing a command via system(). the cmd prompt pops up every time while executing it. how to prevent that.??

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `system()`, it's a primitive way of running sub-processes in that it affords little control over *how* they're run.

Windows provides much finer grained control over sub-processes, such as with the [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call. A great amount of control can be exerted by using the `lpStartupInfo` parameter in that call, things such as whether the window is minimised, maximised, hidden and so on, and what to use for standard input, output and error handles.

Comment: sprintf(command,"netstat -ano | find \"%d\">%s",Port_Number,Log_file_path);

Comment: i'm running above 'command' can CreateProcess do exactly the same??

Comment: @Abhi, yes, though it may take a little extra work with the piping.